# Spring Bean gives NullPointerException but is not null

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I am using Spring with XML configuration to setup bean dependencies, in a text editor program in which i am using JavaFX for GUI. For the file chooser, I have a File Manager class that should have the application's stage injected into it. I have 2 methods printing the Stage object to see if it is null or not. In the `init()`method, the object prints successfully, outputting `javafx.stage.Stage@1cdcac0e`. But when I call the `open()` method I get an error.

Fisrt of all, this is how my beans are configured in Beans.xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="main" class="config.Main" scope="singleton" init-method="initiate">

    </bean>

    <bean id = "fileManager" class="files.FileManager" scope="singleton" init-method="init">
        <property name="ownerWindow" value="#{main.primaryStage}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "editor" class = "controllers.Editor" init-method="init">
        <property name="fileManager">
            <bean id="fileManager" class="files.FileManager"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my File Manager class.

```
package files;

import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FileManager {
    Stage ownerWindow;
    FileChooser fileChooser;

    public void open() {
        System.out.println(ownerWindow);
    }

    public void setOwnerWindow(Stage ownerWindow) {
        this.ownerWindow = ownerWindow;
    }
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(ownerWindow);
    }
}
```

My main class is this:

```
package config;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/Beans.xml");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    public Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
    Parent root;
    String rootPath = "/views/Editor.fxml";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        root = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(rootPath));
        this.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        this.primaryStage.show();

    }

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }
    public void initiate() {
        System.out.println(primaryStage);
    }
}
```

The `initiate()` method in `Main` prints the same line as the `init()` method in FileManager, so I assume that the `primaryStage` is being injected successfully by Spring into the FileManager class.
Despite this, when I call `open()` from a third class, namely `Editor` class, I get NullPointerException:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.Editor.openNewFile(Editor.java:15)`

The `Editor` class is the controller for the GUI of my application, it has a FileManager instance that should be injected by Spring, and in it´s `init()` method which simply prints the FileManager object, the program outputs `files.FileManager@668188db`, so I assume the instance is being injected successfully and should not be null.
My Editor class is as follows:

```
package controllers;

public class Editor {
    //Spring bean
    private FileManager fileManager;
    @FXML TextArea page;
    @FXML Menu menuFile;

    @FXML private void openNewFile() {
        fileManager.open();
    }

    public void setFileManager(FileManager fileManager) {
        this.fileManager = fileManager;
    }
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(fileManager);
    }

}
```

The `openNewFile()` method is where the error is thrown.
My fxml file in case it is of any help:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        fx:controller="controllers.Editor">
   <children>
       <MenuBar layoutX="188.0" layoutY="14.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="575.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
           <Menu fx:id="menuFile" mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
               <MenuItem text="New" onAction="#openNewFile"/>
               <MenuItem text="Open"/>
               <MenuItem text="Open Recent"/>
               <MenuItem text="Save"/>
               <MenuItem text="Save as"/>
               <MenuItem text="Close"/>
           </Menu>
       </MenuBar>
      <BorderPane layoutX="250.0" layoutY="178.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0">
        <center>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="550.0" prefWidth="500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
                <children>
                    <TextArea fx:id="page" layoutX="186.0" layoutY="100.0" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                        <padding>
                            <Insets right="10.0" />
                        </padding>
                    </TextArea>
                </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You have 2 instances of `FileManager`. One with a dependency the other without. You should reference the first `FileManager` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Your NPE indicates that the `Editor` instance causing the NPE ist *not* the one created by Spring. Can you show us how you're getting the `Editor` instance? (nonetheless, you're also creating 2 `FileManager` instances; use `<property name="fileManager" ref="fileManager"/>` on the `editor` definition)

Comment: @M.Deinum I removed the second `FileManager` (the one inside editor bean) but I still get the same results

Comment: Removing it won't help as that will make it null, you have to put the reference to the top-level one in there. Also defining something in the `Beans.xml` doesn't mean that is the instance used by Java-FX, I suspect you need to do more to have proper integration.

Comment: @Simon The `Editor` is a controller for the javaFX fxml file. I assume it is being instantiated by JavaFX when the application starts. This is all the code I wrote. Also, I removed the second `FileManager` instance but still getting the same error

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I understand. I am sorry, I explained poorly, inside my editor bean I now have `<property name="fileManager" ref="fileManager"/>`

Comment: JavaFX is controlling your instance, not Spring. So defining it with Spring and not have Spring control it won't really work.

Comment: I tried using `loader.setController(context.getBean("editor"))` to set my JavaFX controller to the one Spring instantiates, but the error still remains

Comment: Okay, so, now it works. I was using `setController`after calling `loader.load()`, inverting the other of the method calls removes my error. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Simon and @M. Deinum, the `NullPointerException` was thrown because the `Editor` instance created by Spring, was not the instaance calling the `openNewFile()` method, rather, JavaFX was the one controlling my instance. Setting the JavaFX controller using `loader.setController(context.getBean("editor))`, rather than setting it in the fxml file fixed my issue. The `Main` class's `start()` method now looks like this:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    loader.setController(context.getBean("editor"));
    root = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(rootPath));
    this.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    this.primaryStage.show();

}
```